# Grub-install error: disk 'crpytouuid/<uuid>' not found

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, grub, disk-encryption, cryptsetup

I followed [fdiblen's guide on Arch Linux Installation with a Fully encrypted disk and Btrfs filesystem](https://github.com/fdiblen/Arch-Linux-Dell-XPS13-9350) that uses `cryptsetup`.

I'm at the bootloader stage where I'm trying to `grub-install` with these new lines in my `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=/dev/nvme0n1p3:crpytroot:allow-discards"
```

And while executing the line

```
grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/nvme0n1
```

I got the error:

```
Grub-install: error: disk 'crpytouuid/0cebxxxxxxxxxxx' not found
```

I have tried goolging `crpytouuid` and strangely I didn't get any useful result.

I went to check my `/dev/disk/by-uuid` and saw that `0cebxxxxxxxxxxx` is indeed the uuid of my third partition `nvme0n1p3` (which is where `/` is).

So I did `grub-install` again but with `--verbose` and this is what I get:

[image: img_3815]

As you can see in the screenshot `grub-install` logs that

`/dev/mapper/cryptroot is not present.`

so that can be where the problem is but doing `ls /dev/mapper/cryptroot` shows that `/dev/mapper/cryptroot` exists.

I also tried changing

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=/dev/nvme0n1p3:crpytroot:allow-discards"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=/dev/disk/by-uuid/0cebxxxxxxxxxxx:crpytroot:allow-discards root=/dev/mapper/cryptroot"
```

and got the same error.

Comment: Your cryptdevice is wrong: you want a space, not a `:` between the dm-name and the option `allow-discards`.

Comment: @jasonwryan that doesn't solve a thing. still the same error.

Comment: Well, it did solve the issue of your cryptdevice line being completely wrong... But you're welcome anyway.

Comment: @jasonwryan the parser will just ignore it anyway. it really doesn't change a thing here.

Comment: @jasonwryan also can you send me a link to a doc that validate what you have said (i.e. showing that `:` is the wrong syntax.)? now that will be a lot more useful.